# pdo prepare SELECT execute causes ErrorCode 42000

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've got a `SELECT` statement that is returning Error Code 42000.

From what I've found, Error Code 42000 means I have an invalid statement:

```
public function getDataSet($start = 0, $count = 10000) {
    $sql =
        'SELECT e.record_id, e.identifier, e.equipment_type, t.desc_short as type_name, ' .
            'e.desc_short, e.alias, e.afe, e.desc_long, l.desc_short as location_name, e.reserved_by ' .
        'FROM EngineeringDB_Equipment e  ' .
            'LEFT JOIN tbl_code_values l ON (e.location=l.record_id) ' .
            'LEFT JOIN tbl_code_values t ON (e.equipment_type=t.record_id)  ' .
        'WHERE (e.deleted_on=0) ' .
        'ORDER BY e.identifier asc ' .
        'LIMIT :start,:count; ';
    $this->columns = array('record_id', 'identifier', 'equipment_type', 'type_name', 'desc_short', 'alias', 'afe', 'desc_long', 'location_name', 'reserved_by');
    $cmd = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $cmd->bindValue(':start', (int)$start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $cmd->bindValue(':count', (int)$count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $res = $cmd->execute();
    if ($res) {
        $table = $cmd->fetchAll();
    } else {
        $table = array('Error Code' => $cmd->errorCode());
    }
    return ($table);
}
```

So, I took the text of the `$sql`, and ran that through **MySQL Workbench** on the database:

```
SELECT e.record_id, e.identifier, e.equipment_type, t.desc_short as type_name,
e.desc_short, e.alias, e.afe, e.desc_long, l.desc_short as location_name, e.reserved_by
FROM EngineeringDB_Equipment e
LEFT JOIN tbl_code_values l ON (e.location=l.record_id)
LEFT JOIN tbl_code_values t ON (e.equipment_type=t.record_id)
WHERE (e.deleted_on=0)
ORDER BY e.identifier asc
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Yes, `$start`=0 and `$count`=10.

That runs fine, so the problem should not be with the SQL, but rather with something that I am binding on. (???) Does anyone see what that is?

Why does the PHP/PDO code fail?

Comment: just a guess. if you remove the 2 `(int)` casts, does it work?

Comment: Rats. I wished it was. That did not get it @Michael.

Comment: Try putting hard-coded values in the `limit`.  MySQL can be finicky about those arguments.

Comment: if you do somthing like `settype($start, 'integer');` at the beginning, you can just put the values into the query and it will be safe from sql injections

Comment: @GordonLinoff: That worked. Why? Should I leave it hard coded? I don't like doing that, but it is only something the software guys are calling.

Comment: Does it work when you replace :start and :count by $start and $count and leave out the bindValue for testing purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is very finicky about `limit`.  To quote the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) (the last refuge of scoundrels):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
>   exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

I added the observation as a comment because I wasn't sure if your use was similar enough to the first bullet.  Apparently, you need to build the string with the values rather than using parameters.

Can anyone say "SQL injection"?  If this is a concern, it should be easy enough to validate that the values are actually non-negative integers -- no more, no less (lest you get a syntax error of a different sort).

Comment: So what is the final solution that made it running? I missed it somehow. Could you explain it to me, please?

Comment: @tswaehn . . . something like `'limit '.$start.' '.$count` in the query (although value checking is recommended).

Answer (score 1):

For me the code looks good. Could be the placeholders. As far as I know "count" is one of the special words in SQL and I use the placeholders with a space before and afterwards.